# varnish not working after applied turpentine settings

Tags: varnish, turpentine

I am running CE1.7 and have a nginx cluster(x3 nginx) running behind a dedicated varnish server.
After the initial varnish installation, I can see the varnish info in the header which means its running fine.
And then I cleared magento cache and enabled turpertine cache in the admin panel, and put in the right IPs for varnish and backend server(using a separate load balance IP) settings and clicked "save", it applied successfully and saved;however, the varnish doesn't seem to be working normally, as I can cannot find any varnish names in the header anymore.

Attached are my turpentine setting screenshots.

Thanks very much for the help.
[image]

[image]

[image]
these are the other settings I used. looks like varnish is bypassed everytime.

Answer (score 0):

The varnish Headers are only applied to the Response when the Debug Info is enabled I think.

To track your varnish cache hits you can also execute `varnishstat` on your server. It gives you an Overview of the Requests including a hit/miss ratio.

There are also some other factors that could make your varnish just bypass the request. Looking at the default.vcl carefully (even if it seems unreadable first) might give you a hint.

For example: There is a rule somewhere that just bypasses the request if a HTTP Authentication Header is sent.

Answer (score 0):

As David Verholen mentioned, you can use `varnishstat` to see if Varnish is working. Another option is to turn on the varnish bypass from the *cache management* screen and see if you're seeing the warning message that's generated when the bypass cookie is detected. Another nice tool is `varnishhist` which will show you a nice diagram indicating cache hits/misses on page load.

Our [debugging Varnish](https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/wiki/Debugging-Varnish#page-source-changes) page may be helpful.

Also - *remember* that the current default behavior is for each request to *bypass* Varnish for the first hit to make sure a proper session is generated.

Answer (score -1):

I think the default Backend Port is 8080, unless you changed it of course...

I also use Normalize Cookie Regex of #mydomain.com# and Normalized Cookie Target of www.mydomain.com

And posting a Screen of your Backend Varnish Options might also be helpful ;)